# Bind XML data(file) to an grid view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

can i bind an XML file to an grid view ? if we can then how can i do this in android.

Comment: I guess you want to read some data from an XML-File and put those data in a GridView?

Comment: yes i want read data from xml file and then bind it to the gridview

Comment: So, show your XML-data and tell us _how_ you want to add _what_ to the GridView.

Comment: i want show 4 fields into gridview they are FirstName, LastName, DOB, MobileNumber.

Comment: Basically i m doing an search functionality where user can search data by name and then on Search button click i want to display this data into GridView in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a performant and fast search, you'll want to use a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) ([Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)). You can use the [Search-Interface provided by Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) to do this the normal way.You can specify the Activity and the art your results are presented to the user.

Also, for the Database, you'll want to use a [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to access your Database.

Comment: Thanks for all Ur support, but can you give any example or any link from where i can easily learn 1. database creation in android 2. binding of retrived data into grid view and 3. Search functionality implementation.

Comment: Have you read the Links i posted? To bind that Data you read from your Database, you can create the Elements for your GridView using Java and add it to the Layout. But a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) might be better for this.